# What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?

Tags: macros, nesting

I've seen sometimes that people use a double pound sign (`##`) when defining/using arguments.

What is the difference between the normal argument, `#1`, and the double sign one, `##1`? Are there any restrictions for its use? Can you list the good practices, if any, for this type of arguments.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It allows using arguments in nested macro definitions.

In

```
\def\a#1{\def\b#1{...}}
```

the macro `\b` would not have an argument, since `#1` belongs to `\a` and would be replaced by its argument.

However,

```
\def\a#1{\def\b##1{...}}
```

defines `\b` with an argument. During expansion

- `#1` will be replaced by a parameter
- `##` becomes `#`

Then `\b` can use `#1` instead of the original `##1`.

It follows, that for each level of nesting you need to double the number of `#` characters:

```
\def\a#1{\def\b##1{\def\c####1{...}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\a#1{\def\b##1{#1 ##1}}
\begin{document}
\a{x} % consequence: \def\b#1{x #1}
\b{y} % prints: x y
\end{document}
```

In LaTeX syntax this would be:

```
\newcommand{\a}[1]{%
  \newcommand{\b}[1]{#1 ##1}}
```

or, as `\a` and `\b` are already defined, which you would see if you would try it in the small example,

```
\renewcommand{\a}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\b}[1]{#1 ##1}}
```

Comment: Why does one need to double each time, i.e. `#`, `##`, `####` etc., rather than adding a hash sign for each level, i.e. `#`, `##`, `###` etc.?

Comment: @MickG two possible answers, 1 that's just the way it is or 2 because `##` is replaced by `#` just as `#1` is replaced by the first argument, and multiple doubling is just a consequence of that.

Comment: I just compiled `\documentclass{article}\def\a#1{\def\b##1{#1 ##1}}\begin{document}\b{y}\end{document}` and I got something like and \underbar{y}: any reason why?

Comment: @pluton you didn't call `\a{…}` so the built-in `\b` was used. Try `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\b{y}\end{document}` to see that `\b{y}` has this `\underbar{y}` behaviour by default.

Comment: In other words, nesting 64 deep will create an absolute desaster. I wonder if Saint Knuth has thought about that.