# Nesting command definitions more than two levels

Tags: macros, nesting

How do you access macro arguments if the macros are nested by more than two levels?

To explain it in more detail:
Creating a new command in another command (nesting command definitions), it is possible to implement something like [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) of a command. This is useful for example if a command, which is often called, has two arguments and one changes less frequently than the other:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\one}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\two}[1]{#1, ##1}%
    }
    \one{a} % Partial application, nothing gets printed
    \two{b} \quad \two{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately this does not work, if there is another level of nesting involved:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\one}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\two}[1]{%
            \newcommand{\three}[1]{#1, ##1, ###1}%
        }
    }
    \one{a} % First partial application -> Error
    \two{b} % Second partial application
    \three{c}
\end{document}
```

The error occurs in the marked line with the following message:

```
[LaTeX] Line 8: Illegal parameter number in definition of \two.<to be read again>                    a
l.0 \one{c}
         % First partial application -> Error
```

As substituting `\one{a}` by `\one{1}` in the above code leads to the output `1, b, b`, I think  that `###1` is interpreted as `##{#1}`. So `###1` is expanded to `##a` or `##1`, respectively. The first one obviously fails, where the second one compiles but leads to an unexpected result. I tested the commands from `xparse`, too, and the problem seems to be identical.

To rephrase the question above: How do you have `###1` interpreted as `{###1}` instead of `##{#1}` when using the nested command definitions? Why is `##1` in the first example interpreted as `{##1}` instead of `#{#1}`?

I know that it is possible to avoid the third level of nesting by some sort of currying as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\one}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\two}[1]{\helper{#1, ##1}}%
    }
    \newcommand{\helper}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\three}[1]{%#1, ##1}%
    }
    \one{1} % First partial application
    \two{b} % Second partial application by currying
    \three{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems less intuitive and more complicated to me to use two levels of nesting twice instead of three levels of nesting once and I would like to understand how the third level of nesting is used.

Comment: You need four `#`s in the definition of `\three`: something like `\newcommand{\three}[1]{#1, ##1, ####1}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works indeed. Can you please add an answer, so that I can vote for it? I am also very interested in an explanation why that works …

Comment: Related, which also gives a similar explanation as in Gonzalo's answer: [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (`##1`) in an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/5764)

Comment: Thanks, I found a lot of related questions, but I missed this one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use four `#`s in the second nesting level:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\one}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\two}[1]{%
            \newcommand{\three}[1]{#1, ##1, ####1}%
        }
    }
    \one{a} 
    \two{b} 
    \three{c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following quote from *TeX by Topic* gives an explanation (further details in section **11.5.5 The macro parameter character**):

> When TEX’s input processor scans a macro definition text, it inserts a
>   parameter token for any occurrence of a macro parameter character
>   followed by a digit. In effect, a parameter token in the replacement
>   text states ‘insert parameter number such and such here’. Two
>   parameter characters in a row are replaced by a single one.