# Escape hash symbol (#) in inner macro definition

Tags: macros, nesting, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (##1) in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

I'm quite sure this question has been asked many times but I can't find the answer.

I'd like to make a macro defining a new macro but I can't get the arguments working. How do I escape the parameter place-holders e.g. #1 for the inner command?
Here is an absolutely senseless minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\defprint}[1]{%
    \newcommand{\print}[1]{#1\#1}
}
\begin{document}

\defprint{foo}
\print{bar}
\print{boo}

\end{document}
```

Gives "foo#1 foo#1" but I want it to be "foobar fooboo".

Additionally I'd like to know how to do the same in plain Tex using `\def`. I'd expect something like the following, but the backslash seems to be the wrong kind of escape character too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\defprint#1{%
    \def\print\#1{#1\#1}
}
\begin{document}

\defprint{foo}
\print{bar}
\print{boo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tricky one to search for!  I think your question will be answered by reading this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/86  If so, we'll probably close this as a duplicate of that.  If not, please comment (or edit your question) to specify to what still confuses you.

Comment: Following links also led me to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51819/86 which looks useful as well.

Comment: I added the [tag:nesting] tag to the presumable original question.

Comment: Ok thanks Andrew, it's that simple when one knows what to search for. Thanks a lot, the question can be closed. Hopefully it helps others to find the answer as well.

Comment: Great!  That's the good thing about duplicates: each makes it easier to find the original question and answer as it adds more search terms.