# How do you define one macro with arguments inside another

Tags: macros

How do I define a `\newcommand` (or in LaTeX 3 a `\NewDocumentCommand`) which itself defines a `\newcommand` with arguments. For example in

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}[1]
{
\newcommand{#1}[2]
    {\#1 \#2}
}

\test{\you}
\you{3}{4}
\end{document}
```

I would like the output to be "3 4" not "#1 #2" as I want the #1 #2 to be interpreted in the internal `\newcommand` as arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this works. (It also works with `xparse` in the same way.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[2]{%
    ##1 and ##2}}
\test{you}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xtest} {m}
  {%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname #1\endcsname {mm}
    {##1 and also ##2}%
  }
\xtest{andher}

\begin{document}

\you{3}{4}

\test{me}
\me{5}{6}

\andher{7}{8}

\xtest{andhim}
\andhim{9}{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Out of curiosity, if I want to define a newcommand within a newcommand within a newcommand... n levels deep does ##...#1 reference the argument (where there are n#s)?

Comment: If you nest another level, you need to double the `#` again (`####1`).

Comment: @NateAckerman: See [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (`##1`) in an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/5764), [Nesting command definitions more than two levels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51819/5764) and [Why do parameters of `\renewcommand` need to double up the `#` within a `\foreach`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71632/5764).

Answer (score 3):

The [LaTeX2e kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) defined `\@namedef{<csname>}` that could be used exactly for this purpose, as it is defined as:

```
\def\@namedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
```

It sets up the definition of its argument as a control sequence, awaiting the actual replacement text as part of the usual `\def` construction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\@namedef{#1}##1##2{##1 and ##2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{you}\you{3}{4}

\end{document}
```

`\namedef{<csname>}` expands to `\expandafter\def\csname <csname>\endcsname`, which expands to `\def\<csname>`.