# Illegal parameter number with \docsvlist

Tags: macros, errors, lists, etoolbox

I'm trying to define a macro that take as an input a CSV list and create an item list.
`etoolbox` comes just handy for this and the macro I'm using is

```
\begin{itemize}
   \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[] #1}
   \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\participants}
\end{itemize}
```

where `\participants` is the CSV list of items to `itemize`.

My problem is that when I insert this macro as a newcommand definition like

```
\newcommand{\listparticipants}{
   \begin{itemize}
 \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[] #1}
 \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\participants}
   \end{itemize}
}
```

I get the following error message

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \listparticipants.
<to be read again> 
               1
l.29 }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See: [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (##1) in an argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following definition of `\listparticipants`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\listparticipants}[1]{
   \begin{itemize}
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[] ##1}
     \docsvlist{#1}
   \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\listparticipants{Tom,Dick,Harry}
\end{document}
```

Note that you're redefining a command within another one. For the parameter text to be correctly referenced, you need to double the parameter text `#`s. So, `#1` refers to the argument to `\listparticipants`, while `##1` refers to the argument to `\do`.

This convention would hold even if you didn't require `\listparticipants` to take an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\listparticipants}{
   \begin{itemize}
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[] ##1}
     \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\participants}
   \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\def\participants{Tom,Dick,Harry}
\listparticipants
\end{document}
```

Note that the first MWE might be a better approach, since it allows you to format your list of participants (using, say, `\textbf{Tom},\textit{Dick},\textsf{Harry}`), while the second won't work properly with such definitions due to expansion.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid `\docsvlist` if you switch to `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\listparticipants}{ >{\SplitList{,}}m}
 {%
  \begin{itemize}
  \ProcessList{#1}\lpitem
  \end{itemize}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\lpitem}{m}{\item #1} % just to allow for further customization

\begin{document}
\listparticipants{Tom,Dick,Harry}
\end{document}
```

You can split the list given as argument at commas; then `\ProcessList{#1}\lpitem` will do in turn `\lpitem{Tom}`, `\lpitem{Dick}` and `\lpitem{Harry}`.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, you can use another handy macro from `etoolbox`, `\DeclareListParser`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareListParser*{\iterateparticipants}{,}

\newcommand{\listparticipants}[1]{%
\begin{itemize}
  \iterateparticipants{\item}{#1}
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\listparticipants{Tom,Dick,Harry}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

There we go. `:)`

Comment: One has to watch out for trailing spaces in the values, because they aren't trimmed off. This isn't relevant in the present case, but might be in other situations.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I fixed the code. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to process comma separated lists is to use PGF's `\foreach` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\listparticipants}[1]{
   \begin{itemize}
        \foreach \particpant in {#1} {%
            \item \particpant
        }
   \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
    \listparticipants{Tom,Dick,Harry}
\end{document}
```