# Manipulating arguments to a macro inside an argument

Tags: conditionals, expansion

In LaTeX, I have a macro `\p` (okay, it's `\paragraph`, but perhaps the specific macro is not relevant?) with one argument. Sometimes I use it as

```
\p{plain text}
```

and sometimes as

```
\p{\t{alternate 1}{alternate 2}}
```

(where `\t` is `hyperref`'s `\texorpdfstring`, but again, perhaps it doesn't matter). I'd like to redefine or modify `\p` and/or `\t` so that `\p{plain text}` continues to display as normal, but `\p{\t{alt 1}{alt 2}}` changes to

```
\p{\t{\extraformatting{alternate 1}}{alternate 2}}
```

where `\extraformatting` is some formatting command to be determined.

It has to be done in a way such that what I will physically write in the file is still `\p{}`. Well, it doesn't *have* to; this whole exercise is not strictly a requirement, but something that I feel like I should know how to do, but I can't remember.

I got a bit of a start using the `\iffirsttoken` conditional in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100213/125), whose "API" is

```
\iffirsttoken{<tokenlist>}{<token>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

I figure I can reimplement `\p` to test `#1` against `\t` and if it matches, somehow insert `\extraformatting` into the first argument, and otherwise do nothing:

```
\def\p#1{%
  \iffirsttoken{#1}{\t}{%
    ...something goes here...
  }{%
    #1
  }%
}
```

but I can't quite figure out what would go in that `true` condition. Any help?

---

Here is a MWE that can be copied and pasted:

```
\documentclass{article}

% stands in for \paragraph - this is preexisting
\def\p#1{p( #1 )p}
% stands in for \texorpdfstring - this is preexisting
\def\t#1#2{t( #1 )t( #2 )t}

\makeatletter
\def\iffirsttoken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@first@token\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}%
  \expandafter\ifx\@first@token#2\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}
\makeatother

% the extra formatting to apply to the first argument of \t
% this I define myself
\def\e#1{e( #1 )e}

\def\p#1{%
  \iffirsttoken{#1}{\t}{%
    % ...something goes here...
  }{%
    #1
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  The following should be ``p( t( e( arg1 )e )t( arg2 )t )p''

  \p{\t{arg1}{arg2}}

  The following should be ``p( text )p''

  \p{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\t` necessarily appear only as the first token in `\p`?

Comment: Yes, in my scenario if `\t` appears in the argument to `\p` it will be the first token.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\originalp\p
\LetLtxMacro\originalt\t
\newif\ifp

\renewcommand\p[1]{\ptrue\originalp{#1}\pfalse}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\t[2]{%
  \originalt{\apply@extraformatting{#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\apply@extraformatting{%
  \ifp
    \expandafter\extraformatting
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

In this case `\t` need not be the first token in the argument to `\p`.

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it I figured this out when I was just about to submit the question. I can use the fact that `\def` allows one to specify complex patterns from which arguments will be recognized, not just `\def#1#2` etc. So I can write `\def\e\t#1#2` to recognize and scoop up `\e` (the extra formatting), `\t` (the `\texorpdfstring`), and its two arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

% ... lines omitted ...
\makeatother

\def\e\t#1#2{\t{e( #1 )e}{#2}}
\let\oldp=\p
\def\p#1{\iffirsttoken{#1}{\t}{\oldp{\e#1}}{\oldp{#1}}}

\begin{document}
 % ... lines omitted ...
\end{document}
```

I make no claims of this being robust, so perhaps someone else can do better.