# Autoref: show counter befor label

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

This might look weird but it is culture specific. Is it possible to somehow change autoref to render "1 Figure" instead of "Figure 1"?

Comment: Probably, can you make a MWE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general solution for different kind of floats (figures, tables, algorithms, etc.) you can redefine `\autoref` using the number from `\ref` followed by the float name, without the number, from `\nameCref` (provided by the package `cleveref`). If you also want to change the captions then you can declare a custom format using the `caption` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{switched}{#2 #1}
\captionsetup{labelformat=switched}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\ref*{#1} \nameCref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{this is a figure}
\caption{a caption}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

See \autoref{fig:example} for an example.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: nice solution... It change the captions too... mine doesn't change the captions

Answer (score 4):

I found this subject here:
[Gobbling an argument if it starts with #](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100209/gobbling-an-argument-if-it-starts-with)

And I changed it to give you the required result.

The code is:

```
\makeatletter
% this is found in latex.ltx:
% \def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\iffirsttoken#1#2{%
  % define \@first@token to be the once expanded \@car of the first argument
  % i.e. the first token or balanced group:
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@first@token\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}%
  % test if the expansion of \@first@token is the same as #2:
  \expandafter\ifx\@first@token#2\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldhref\autoref
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{%
  %\oldhref{#1}%
  \iffirsttoken{#1}{t}{~\ref{#1} Table}%
}
```

and your tables (only them) have to start with the letter t as first letter of their label...

Test it... You can expand the code for figures etc

Edit MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}



\makeatletter
% this is found in latex.ltx:
% \def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\iffirsttoken#1#2{%
  % define \@first@token to be the once expanded \@car of the first argument
  % i.e. the first token or balanced group:
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@first@token\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}%
  % test if the expansion of \@first@token is the same as #2:
  \expandafter\ifx\@first@token#2\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldhref\autoref
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{%
  %\oldhref{#1}%
  \iffirsttoken{#1}{t}{~\ref{#1} Table}\relax%
  \iffirsttoken{#1}{f}{~\ref{#1} Figure}%
}

\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{}\label{tst}
 \begin{tabular}{ c c}
\hline
 Here & is\\
  a & table\\\hline
 \end{tabular}

\end{table}

We can refer to the table as Table \ref{tst}
with the \verb|\ref| command or to refer with 
\verb|\autoref| and have \autoref{tst}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \caption{}\label{fst}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

We can refer to the figure as Figure \ref{fst}
with the \verb|\ref| command or to refer with 
\verb|\autoref| and have \autoref{fst}

\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]