# Undefined control sequence \pgfmath@

Tags: macros, errors, expansion, pgfkeys, pgfmath

Why does the following code give me this error message?

### Error

> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> --- TeX said ---
>   \pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@
>
> l.28   \draw (\getWickersonLeft{c},0)
>                                        -- (\getWickersonRight{c},5);

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/wickersons/.cd,
  execute style/.style={#1},                           
  execute macro/.style={execute style/.expand once=#1}, 
  left/.code={\gdef\wickersonsleft{#1}},
  right/.code={\gdef\wickersonsright{#1}}
}

\def\getWickersonLeft#1{\csname wickerson#1left\endcsname}
\def\getWickersonRight#1{\csname wickerson#1right\endcsname}

\newcommand*\defWickersonMacros[3]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname wickerson#1left\endcsname{#2}
  \expandafter\edef\csname wickerson#1right\endcsname{#3}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=-1mm]%
  \foreach \x/\xvalue in {c/{left=67,right=77}} { 
    \pgfkeys{/wickersons/.cd, execute macro=\xvalue} 
    \expandafter\defWickersonMacros{c}{\wickersonsleft}{\wickersonsright}
  }
  \draw (\getWickersonLeft{c},0) -- (\getWickersonRight{c},5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\defWickersonMacros` needs `\xdef`s here … (by the way, `\csname` will expand everything it will encounter so you don't need to expand `\x` for it which I guess the lonely `\expandafter` in the loop is a remainder of).

Comment: also `\expandafter\defWickersonMacros{` expands `{` which isn't expandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would instead use the `\pgfkeysvalueof` way of defining things. This is a very convoluted way of avoiding the real power of `pgfkeys` because instead of keys you are using dummy macros. Consider sending all your options to some keys belonging to a family.

Here the problem is that the argument of a macro is used inside another definition so `#` chars should be doubled.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/wickersons/.cd,
  execute style/.style={#1},                           
  execute macro/.style={execute style/.expand once=#1}, 
  left/.code={\xdef\wickersonsleft{#1}},
  right/.code={\xdef\wickersonsright{#1}}
}

\edef\getWickersonLeft#1{\csname wickerson#1left\endcsname}
\edef\getWickersonRight#1{\csname wickerson#1right\endcsname}

\newcommand*\defWickersonMacros[3]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname wickerson##1left\endcsname{#2}% Double ##
  \expandafter\xdef\csname wickerson##1right\endcsname{#3}% Double ##
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=-1mm]%
  \foreach \x/\xvalue in {c/{left=67,right=77}} { 
    \pgfkeys{/wickersons/.cd, execute macro=\xvalue} 
    \defWickersonMacros{c}{\wickersonsleft}{\wickersonsright}
  }

\draw (\getWickersonLeft{c},0) -- (\getWickersonRight{c},5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output :)

[image]

Comment: (Actually, he is re-creating PGF keys. The value of the key `/wickersons/left` would be stored in `\pgfk@/wickersons/left/name` and `\pgfkeysvalueof` doesn’t make anything else as `\csname`-ing that.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this @percusse. I don't understand why I need `##1` though. Why doesn't the same logic apply to my `#2` and `#3`? I would say that none of them are inside the other definition; they are just used to *create* that other definition.

Comment: @JohnWickerson There you go :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument

Comment: Thanks @percusse, but I still think the double `##` is wrong. Parameter `1` is not an argument to the command being defined. It's used to construct the *name* of the command being defined. For instance, `\defWickersonMacros{percusse}{foo}{bar}` should expand to `\xdef\wickersonpercusseleft{foo}`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson When `##1` is expanded it becomes `#1`.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want it to become `#1`, I want it to become `percusse`. (I'm sorry, you're probably right about this, but I just don't see why yet.) I think the expansion sequence should be as follows. Start with `\defWickersonMacros{percusse}{foo}{bar}`. Then expand `\defWickersonMacros`, subsituting the actual for the formal parameters, to give `\expandafter\xdef\csname wickerson percusse left\endcsname{foo}`. Then expand the `\expandafter`, to give `\xdef\wickersonpercusseleft{foo}`, which is what I want.

Answer (score 3):

After [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) has [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114307/16595) your question, I want to give you an alternative on how to process your list with the abilities of PGF keys and TikZ.

Some of the code is inspired by another recent question of yours.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/wickersons}{
  add path/.code args={#1}{%
    \begingroup% a group so the initial values don't need to be repeated but can be set in a scope above
      \pgfqkeys{/wickersons/path vars}{#1}% set only the keys that are given in '#1', other wise the current value will be used (probably the .initial one)
      % now expand everything (but the label which may contain unexpandable stuff, we only want to expand that once)
      \edef\pgf@tempa{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/wickersons/path vars/name}/.style={insert path={%
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/wickersons/path vars/left},0) -- node [every wickersons label/.try] {\unexpanded\expandafter{\wickersons@pathvars@label}}
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/wickersons/path vars/right},5)}}}}%
      % and get it out of this group
      \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgf@tempa
    \endgroup
    % the 'path vars' now contain all there values before 'add path' was used
    %
    % have you seen the extra pair of braces in \pgf@tempa? Those where necessary, otherwise I had to use
    % \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\pgf@tempa}
    % here
    \expandafter\tikzset\pgf@tempa
  },
  path vars/.cd,
   name/.initial=path,% if 'add path' has been used without the 'name' key the style would have been named 'path'
   left/.initial=0,   % if 'add path' has been used without the 'left' key the left point would have started at (0,0)
   right/.initial=0,  % ...
   label/.store in=\wickersons@pathvars@label,% or toks
   label=%            % ...
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 x=1mm,
 y=-1mm,
 ->,
 thick,
 every wickersons label/.style={midway, above, sloped},
 /wickersons/add path/.list={%
   {name=foo, left= 2, right=23, label=horse},%
   {name=bar, left=25, right=29, label=sheep},%
   {name=baz, left=31,           label=\textbf{zebra}}%
 }]

  \draw [every wickersons label/.append style={pos=.2}] [foo];
  \draw [bar];
  \draw [every wickersons label/.append style={pos=.4}] [baz]; % uses right=0
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: All this expanding/unexpanding makes my head hurt! Thank you for your suggestions @Qrrbrbirlbel. I have posted another question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114433/constructing-dag-like-diagrams), where I clarify my use-case a bit more, which should make it easier to discuss the best way for me to do things.

Comment: Why this is community wiki, by the way?