# Preventing argument expansion

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, expansion, tikz-styles

TikZ is able to define parametrized styles using arguments like `#1`. If used in `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment`, they mix up with the arguments of the command. The effect is so severe that the following example will not even compile, but cause TeX to stall. Is there a way to prevent command argument expansion and delay it to be handled by TikZ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{fancypicture}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      fancy/.style={circle, draw, fill=#1}
      % The line above here poses the problem.
      % Instead of \newenvironment, this #1 shall be left to be handled by TikZ.
    ]
    \node [fancy=red] at (0, 2) {#1};
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{fancypicture}
  \node [draw] {s};
\end{fancypicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that it would help to put the style declaration in a top-level `\tikzset`. But that would make it global to all pictures in the document, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is discussed in

[What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{fancypicture}[1][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      fancy/.style={circle, draw, fill=##1}
    ]
    \draw[style=help lines] (0cm,0cm) grid[step=1cm] (2cm,2cm);
    \node [fancy=red] at (0,1cm) {#1};
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{fancypicture}[A]
  \node[draw] at (1cm,1cm) {s};
\end{fancypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]