# How to allow # in \newcommand without \# or another way to defer processing of section of code

Tags: macros

I am trying to defer processing of some latex code.

This works,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
here comes a reference
\href{http://www.example.com/doc#list}{doc}
\end{document}
```

but I need to move up the importing of `codeToBeDeferred` (containing the `\href`), and render/process it in the same place. So I changed it to this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\deferredCode}{
    \href{http://www.example.com/doc#list}{doc}
}
\begin{document}
here comes a reference
\deferredCode
\end{document}
```

This works, except for the `#` in the `\href`, note the `#` was not a problem in the original code.

side note: I am reading the code early and deferring processing because the code is merged together by a preprocessor, the preprocessor needs to process the deferred code early, but latex needs to do it latter.

Well all this works, except when the `codeToBeDeferred` has a # in it. `\newcommand` does not like it. If I put a `\` before the `#` it fixes it, however I do not want to do this: there are a lot of historic versions of this code, I don't want to have to remember when I write new code. The code is valid latex when not part of a `\newcommand`

How can I allow a `#` in a `\newcommand`?
or
How else can I defer the processing of this block of code?

---

The `#` is in a `\href` in the deferred code, it works outside of a `\newcommand`.

What I am hoping for, is a wrapper to stop the `#` being a problem. If the `#` is only a problem when in a `\newcommand` then this may be possible.

```
%somePreambleCode
\newcommand{\deferredCode}{
    \wrapper{
        \href{http://www.example.com/doc#list}{doc}
    }
}
%someOtherCode
\deferredCode
```

I know that I can escape the `#` with a `\` (changing it to `\#`), but am hoping for another way.

I don't want to edit the code to be deferred. There is a choice of hundreds of them, I don't want them to be constrained by me doing this deferral trick to fix another problem.

Comment: I think you could clarify a little bit the question. What's exactly what you are trying to achieve? Using `#` as “text”? I think a more particular example would be great.

Comment: If you want to typeset a `#` then you need `\#` in anycase unrelated to `\newcommand`  `\begin{document} a # b \end{document}` is an error you need `a \# b`

Comment: I guess that the OP wants a later execution/expansion of code with some `#` character, however, this stands as a placeholder for the number of a specific argument. As the command `\deferredcode` has no argument, `LaTeX` will complain about a direct `#` occuring somewhere inside the command, especially, if not followed by a number from 1 up to 9.

Comment: @richard: I am unsure whether you rather mean something like `\noexpand` or `\unexpanded`. Could you also explain in short why there are `#` characters in the command body?

Comment: Does your deferred code perhaps itself include definitions which thus use `#1`, _etc._? If so, you are probably looking for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument

Comment: The `\href` info is new. Could you add a minimal compilable example which we could compile to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @JosephWright: However, this `##1` by a nested `\def` or `\(re)newcommand` etc. wouldn't be needed if there is no `#1` at all, or am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You _always_ need to double `#` tokens to allow nesting. Thus `def\foo{\def\foo##1{##1}}` needs two `#` for the inner definition even though the outer one has no parameters.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ok, thanks for that information, I have not done this so far, since there was no need of doing so.

Comment: @richard: If `\href` is used, than you refer to an external document and in this case a `\#` is needed.

Comment: I have added a foot note to question. There is no `\newcommand` of definitions in the deferred code. Just a `\href`, it was working for yours without the deferring (use of `\newcommand`).

Comment: @richard: Well, you have a `\newcommand` in order to define your `\deferredcode` command. And all this cases, as commented by David Carlisle, Joseph Wright, Manuel and me, the `#` character has a special meaning, which must be escaped by using `\#`

Comment: I was hoping that, because the `\href` works outside of a `\newcommand`, that there would be a way to wrap all of the deferred code in the `\new command` to make it behave.

Comment: @richard: Please see the comment by J. Wright below my answer. I think, he  answered it more complete than me;-)

Comment: @richard since you are using `\href` I can think that you load `hyperref` and hence `url` is loaded (you should provide a complete compilable example, as always). Those packages offer capabilities to define urls, so it might be better here to define urls once out of `\newcommand` and then use the defined urls inside it, avoiding problems with `#`.

Comment: I don't want to change the code that is deferred, I added a note about this to question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have looked at `\noexpand` `\unexpanded`, but can not workout if they are what I need.

Comment: @richard `\unexpanded` won't help here as you still end up with a token of category code 6 (macro parameter).

Comment: @richard: I proposed `\noexpand` etc. before I knew about the `\href` issue. I should have removed that comment or writing an update, that it would be of no use.

Answer (score 8):

Once TeX has tokenized input, which occurs for example when you save the input in a macro, then it's not generally straight-forward to alter the nature of the tokens. In particular, this restricts our ability to use verbatim or verbatim-like input in the arguments and definitions of macros. The `\href` command needs to use a verbatim-like approach to allow for example `#` inside hyperlinks, so that causes the problem.

In the question, you've noted that using `\#` is not a usable solution. This the most obvious approach is to alter the category code of `#` for the duration of the block you want to defer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\catcode`\#=12 %
\newcommand*\deferredCode{%
    \href{http://www.example.com/doc#list}{doc}%
}
\catcode`\#=6 %
\begin{document}
here comes a reference
\deferredCode
\end{document}
```

(Category code 12 is 'other' and so is harmless). Of course this prevents the deferred block containing any macro definitions requiring parameters, or at least that you pick some other character for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

When using the reference to external labels, the `#` character is used, according to the hypertext specification, but this means, that has to be escaped with`\#` within another command such as `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\deferredcode}{%
  \href{anotherfile.pdf\#mylabel}{Some Text}
}%

\begin{document}

In chapter \deferredcode we saw that
\end{document}
```

Where `anotherfile.tex` contains

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first}\label{mylabel}%
\end{document}
```

I omitted a screenshot, since it does not reveal much.

Comment: Perhaps note why this is required inside a definition but not outside (verbatim-like reading of arguments is possible only if they've not been tokenized).

Comment: @JosephWright: I will add you comment, with reference to you, of course, but is it possible to prevent the tokenizing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not as good as the other solutions, but why not use this code:

```
\href{http://www.example.com/doc{\char`\#}list}{doc}
```

Make sure to put this as the definition for `\deferredcode` to make it work.

Comment: Or better yet, define a `\hash` command for `\char\number\`\#`

Comment: The `\number` in ``\char\number`\#`` is redundant.  It is probably better to do `\edef\hash{\string#}`, then the command has better chances of getting the link right

Comment: I fixed the `\number`

Answer (score 0):

You can define `\deferredCode` in terms of `\edef` while applying `\string` to problematic characters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\deferredCode{%
  \edef\deferredCode{\noexpand\href{http://www.example.com/doc\string#list}{doc}}%
}%

\begin{document}
here comes a reference
\deferredCode
\end{document}
```

You can define a command which reads one argument in verbatim-catcode-régime and defines another command to apply `\scantokens` to that argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^A=14\relax
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\csname @firstofone\endcsname{^^A
  \endgroup^^A
  \NewDocumentCommand\DefineScantokenscommandFromVerbArg{m+v}{^^A
    \newcommand#1{\scantokens{#2%}}^^A
  }^^A
}%

\DefineScantokenscommandFromVerbArg\deferredCode|\href{http://www.example.com/doc#list}{doc}|

\begin{document}
here comes a reference
\deferredCode
\end{document}
```