# Using \newcommand with arguments inside of \newcommand

Tags: macros

I'm using the following commands inside my main TeX file right after the ToC.

```
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\thepage]{\leftmark}\chead[]{}\rhead[\myentitle]{\thepage}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}
```

I want to put it all into a new command `\MainMatter`. How can I do this? I have just tried to do so, however, I get the following error.

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of `\MainMatter`}.
```

How can this be done?

Comment: use `##` to get a `#`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Apart from `##1`... where is the `\newcommand` inside `newcommand`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\newcommand` definitions with arguments within another `\renewcommand` or  `\newcommand` require a `##1`, `##2` etc. for argument replacement, **even** if the outer command has no arguments at all.

In lack of a MWE, I just 'invented' one, defining the unknown command `\myentitle`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myentitle}{Some unknown text}
\newcommand{\MainMatter}{%
\mainmatter%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ ##1}{}}
\lhead[\thepage]{\leftmark}\chead[]{}\rhead[\myentitle]{\thepage}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{}\rfoot{}
}%

\begin{document}

\MainMatter

\chapter{The very first chapter}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]