# Explain this macro: double hash with no number, \ialign

Tags: tables, macros, plain-tex

This macro is quite old, and I don't know plain TeX very well. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.06em}
\newlength{\cellsize} \setlength{\cellsize}{18\unitlength}
\newsavebox{\cell}
\sbox{\cell}{\begin{picture}(18,18)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){18}}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){18}}
\put(18,0){\line(0,1){18}}
\put(0,18){\line(1,0){18}}
\end{picture}}
\newcommand\cellify[1]{\def\thearg{#1}\def\nothing{}%
\ifx\thearg\nothing
\vrule width0pt height\cellsize depth0pt\else
\hbox to 0pt{\usebox{\cell} \hss}\fi%
\vbox to \cellsize{
\vss
\hbox to \cellsize{\hss$#1$\hss}
\vss}}
\newcommand\tableau[1]{\vtop{\let\\\cr
\baselineskip -16000pt \lineskiplimit 16000pt \lineskip 0pt
\ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr#1\crcr}}}

\begin{document}
  \tableau{ & & & 5 & 6 & 8\\ & & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 5 & 7 & 5}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output.]

As for my confusion, it's mostly coming from

```
\ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr#1\crcr}}}
```

I know a double hash inside a nested macro definition expands to a single hash and allows the inner macro to take arguments, but that doesn't seem to be what's going on here. I have no idea what a single hash alone means. I tried searching but was only able to find explanations for appearances of eg. `##1` rather than `##` or just `#`. It seems to somehow be breaking up the #1 input at alignment characters and passing them to cellify, but the specifics are black magic to me.

The reason I'm wondering is that I was trying to extend the macro to use a different picture (dashed lines) if a certain character was used, but just adding an extra `\if` branch inside `\cellify` comparing `#1` to *e.g.* `-` didn't work. Well, it did if you called `\cellify` on its own, but `\tableau` seems to be giving it more tokens.

I have very little plain TeX experience and am also confused by quite a few other things in this macro that don't seem to be documented well online (`\ialign`; `\cr`; `\crcr`; `\hss`; `\vss`). Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`##` in a macro definition puts `#` in the replacement text (which is why `##1` puts the required `#1` in a nested definition).

So if the argument of `\cellify` is `X` then when that is expanded, `#1` is replaced by `X` and `##` is replaced by `#`

so

```
\ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr#1\crcr}
```

expands to

```
\ialign{&\cellify{#}\cr X\crcr}
```

`\ialign` is a command defined in plain TeX (and also inherited in latex) which uses a syntax closer to the primitive `\halign` than the latex `tabular` but it is essentially doing the same thing.

The first row (up to the first `\cr` is the alignment template. here it begins with `&` which is a special syntax that means any number of columns are allowed, and each cell gets the code `\cellify{...}` where `...` s the cell content between `&`.

In this example there is only one cell in the table and that would be typeset as

```
\cellify{X}
```

---

Here is a version that detects a cell with just `-` and makes a cell with a `!` just as a demo.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.06em}
\newlength{\cellsize} \setlength{\cellsize}{18\unitlength}
\newsavebox{\cell}
\sbox{\cell}{\begin{picture}(18,18)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){18}}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){18}}
\put(18,0){\line(0,1){18}}
\put(0,18){\line(1,0){18}}
\end{picture}}
\def\dashtest{-}
\newcommand\cellify[1]{\def\thearg{#1}\def\nothing{}%
\ifx\thearg\nothing
\vrule width0pt height\cellsize depth0pt\else
\ifx\thearg\dashtest
\hbox to 0pt{\usebox{\cell}\kern-2pt!\hss}%or whetever
\def\thearg{}%
\else
\hbox to 0pt{\usebox{\cell} \hss}\fi\fi
\vbox to \cellsize{
\vss
\hbox to \cellsize{\hss$\thearg$\hss}
\vss}}
\newcommand\tableau[1]{\vtop{\let\\\cr
\baselineskip -16000pt \lineskiplimit 16000pt \lineskip 0pt
\ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr#1\crcr}}}

\begin{document}
  \tableau{ & &-& 5 & 6 & 8\\ & & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 5 & 7 & 5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've asked one further thing in a response to egreg's answer, clarifying why my naive extension of `\tableau` didn't work. I'm sure it's simple if you know the system.

Comment: `\hbox to \cellsize{\hss$a #1 b$\hss}`  doesn't work as `\hbox to \cellsize` is the primitive version of `\makebox[\cellsize]{...}` so the width of the cell is forced to be exactly `\cellsize` and if you put more stuff in then it overprints to the left and right

Comment: @JoshSwanson see updated answer

Answer (score 9):

Let's start from the main part:

```
\ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr#1\crcr}
```

As usual, `#1` will be replaced by the argument given at call time, so it's not very relevant. The macro `\ialign` is defined in Plain TeX as

```
\everycr{}\tabskip\z@skip\halign
```

so it's an “initialized” `\halign`, where some parameters are cleared. The important object is the primitive `\halign`, which is the basis all tables are built on.

The syntax of this primitive is

```
\halign{<templates>\cr<body of the table>}
```

where `<body of the table>` consists of the cells, separated by `&`, and the rows are terminated by `\cr`. Other material can go after `\cr` as argument to `\noalign`.

The `<templates>` are the specifications for each table column, again separated by `&`. A template consists of three parts, traditionally called *u* and *v*, and in between them a “placeholder” `#` should be inserted, which represents the cell's content in the table body. In our case we have a single template; the initial `&` means that the number of columns is unspecified and all of them will share the same template. Here

> *u* = `\cellify{`
>   *v* = `}`

This means that after TeX has determined a cell's contents, it will substitute it with `\cellify{<cell contents>}`.

It's just that simple! A template is very similar to a one parameter macro, but instead of `#1` just `#` is used.

Why doubling it? Because it's inside a definition, in the same spirit as in [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

So, when `\tableau` is expanded, the correct *single* `#` will appear in the main input stream.

The primitive `\crcr` means: add `\cr` if and only if the argument `#1` doesn't provide a closing `\cr` (that, by virtue of the instruction `\let\\\cr` will probably be `\\`). A closing `\cr` is needed for `\halign` to complete its work, and this trick allows the user not to specify a trailing `\\` when using `\tableau`.

You can read about `\hss` and `\vss` in [TeX by Topic](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) (click on the link or type `texdoc texbytopic` in a terminal window) or in the TeXbook; the books have much more about `\halign`.

Comment: Thank you, that's so much clearer. It seems I was mostly missing "templates" in `\halign` and friends. One nagging question: `\ialign` is passing more than just the numbers in my tableau, eg. 5, 6, 8, to `\cellify`. For instance, if I replace `\hss$#1$\hss` with `\hss$a #1 b$\hss` I get weird spacing issues. What is it actually passing and how could I do my proposed extension of `\tableau` where eg. a `-` gives rise to a dotted box? (I can make the dotted box variant of `\cell` myself.)

Comment: @JoshSwanson Are you meaning “dotted borders”? The borders are drawn with `\hrule` and `\vrule`.

Answer (score 3):

The macro discussed here is very curious mix of plain TeX and LaTeX approach. In pure plain TeX it can look like:

```
\def\tableau#1{\vbox{\offinterlineskip \let\\=\cr \ialign{&\cellify{##}\cr #1\crcr}}}
\def\cellify#1{\ifx^#1^\else
   \vbox{\kern-.2pt\hrule
         \hbox to18pt{\kern-.2pt\vrule height12pt depth6pt\hss#1\unskip\hss\vrule\kern-.2pt}
         \hrule \kern-.2pt}%
   \fi
}

\tableau{ & & & 5 & 6 & 8\\ & & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 5 & 7 & 5}

\end
```

And if you need to change `-` to `X` (for example), then you can replace `\hss#1\unskip` by `\hss\tableauA#1\unskip` and you can define:

```
 \def\tableauA#1#2\unskip{\ifx-#1x\else#1#2\unskip\fi}

 \tableau{ & & - & 5 & 6 & 8\\ & & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 5 & 7 & 5}
```