# How to fix Illegal parameter number in definition of a new Tikz command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

This small piece of code isn't working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
%
\newcommand{\Stack}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[stack/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,draw, anchor=center}]
\node[stack=3]  {
\nodepart{one}\texttt{int} 1
\nodepart{two}\texttt{int} 2
\nodepart{three}\texttt{int} 3
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\Stack
\end{document}
```

It gives the following error:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \Stack.
>    
>                      1
>   l.18 }

The code is tested and works fine otherwise. Can someone help please?

Comment: Just set `rectangle split parts=3`, and use `stack` instead of `stack=3`, I'd guess.

Comment: use `##1` not `#1` as the argument does not refer to `\Stack`. But as Torbjørn mentions, you probably does not need to use an argument if the value is always 3

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.I tried the solution given by @TorbjørnT.  It worked very well. Can you make an answer with a small explanation as to what's happening? I will choose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that when you have `#1` in a `\newcommand` definition, that is interpreted as being an argument for the macro itself, and you need to specify how many arguments your macro should take. For example if you define

```
\newcommand\foo{#1}
```

that will throw the same error. The correct definition would be

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}
```

Where the `[1]` states that this macro takes one mandatory argument, the default being zero I think, and you would call the macro as

```
\foo{bar}
```

When you have a style with an argument, that is (probably) akin to having a second macro definition inside the definition of `\Stack`. So to make the `#1` belong to the style, you need to use `##1` instead, as daleif mentioned. The double `#` indicates that the argument is for the "inner" macro. See [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/) for more discussion about that.

But in your case you seem to always have the same argument for that style (`3`), so it would perhaps make more sense to modify the style definition to have `rectangle split parts=3` instead of `rectangle split parts=#1`, and change `stack=3` to `stack` in the node.