# Problem using length operator in Lua

Tags: luatex, lua

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\printdata}{%
  \directlua{
    data = {"a", "b", "c"}
    for i = 1, #data do
      tex.print(data[i])
    end
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \printdata
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \printdata.
```

LuaLaTeX doesn't seem to understand the length operator `#` in `#data`. Somewhere else I read that you must prefix it thus: `\string#data`, but this only works outside the `\newcommand` definition.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: At minimum you need to use `luacode` environment, but in general I strongly recommend putting lua code in separate files and including with `dofile`.

Comment: Your statement, "LuaLaTeX doesn't seem to understand the length operator `#` in `#data`", is somewhat misleading. The issue is that the argument of `\directlua` is *expanded* (in the TeX sense of the word) *before* the Lua code is passed to Lua for further processing. And, because "`#data`" is not a valid expression according to TeX's syntax rules, you get a TeX-based error message, `! Illegal parameter number...`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make a file (say `foo.lua`) containing your Lua code:

```lua
function printeverything()
   data = {"a", "b", "c"}
   for i = 1, #data do
      tex.print(data[i])
   end
end
```

Then in your `.tex` file you can use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile('foo.lua')}
\newcommand{\printdata}{\directlua{printeverything()}}

\begin{document}
  \printdata
\end{document}
```

(You don't need to use a Lua function — you could just dump the function's contents in your file and define `\newcommand{\printdata}{\directlua{dofile('foo.lua')}}` — but if you have multiple chunks of Lua code you may not want to create separate files for each of them.)

---

**Explanation**: When working with Lua code, and putting it in your `.tex` files, sooner or later you'll run into this issue: the TeX engine (LuaTeX) will read through the characters of your `.tex` file assuming certain category codes, and characters like `#` have special meanings in TeX that you don't intend in Lua code. There exists a way of working around this (run `texdoc luacode` to see the [documentation of the `luacode` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/luacode/luacode.pdf)), but IMO there are good reasons to do avoid these workarounds. As that documentation says in the very first paragraph:

> Before presenting the tools in this package, let me insist that the best way to manage a nontrivial piece of Lua code is probably to use an external file and source it from Lua, as explained in the cited document.

The [cited document (`lualatex-doc.pdf`)](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf) says:

> The `luacode` package provides commands and environments that help to varying degrees with some of these problems. However, for everything but trivial pieces of Lua code, it is wiser to use an external file containing only Lua code defining functions, then load it and use its functions. For example:
>
> ```
> \directlua{dofile("my-lua-functions.lua")}
> \newcommand*{\greatmacro}[2]{%
> \directlua{my_great_function("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}", #2)}}
> ```

One of the reasons I prefer putting Lua code in a separate `.lua` file is that your editor probably does better syntax highlighting for the Lua code when it's in an separate `.lua` file. (Similarly, you can get better highlighting when pasting the Lua code here on this website, if it's a separate code block.)

Comment: Great! Thanks. I got it working now. This issue of token expansion and escape codes is always tormenting me, as I have never been able to wrap my head fully around it. Using the `dofile` function circumvents some of the problems related to it.

Comment: @NVaughan Glad it worked. Yes `dofile` helps, and more generally LuaTeX helps a lot with avoiding having to worry about token-expansion: you can pass arguments to Lua functions as in typical programming languages, and so on. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

You can hide `#` to TeX, while making it good for Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\printdata}{%
  \directlua{
    data = {"a", "b", "c"}
    for i = \string##data, 1, -1 do
      tex.print(data[i])
    end
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\printdata

\end{document}
```

This prints

> cba

Note that a direct call to `\directlua` would need a single `#`. The doubling here is because `#` appears in a definition.

What's this about? `#` is a special character for TeX. It is the “prefix” for parameters in definitions (and can be used alone in `\halign`, but it's not the problem here).

When TeX absorbs a definition it doesn't interpret macros and commands, but it ensures that `#` is followed by a digit according to the number of arguments of the macro being defined. If we want to pass `#` to the replacement text of a macro, we need to double it. See [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/) for details.

In this way, the replacement text of `\printdata` will actually contain a single `#`. However, such `#` would be interpreted at a call of the macro and it would appear in a wrong context; but `\string#` transforms `#` into a printable character, so it doesn't harm macro expansion when `\directlua` is executed.

Thus `\string##data`: the doubling means that just `\string#data` is stored in the replacement text of `\printdata`. Since `\directlua` first does TeX macro expansion, Lua will just see `#data` (with a safe `#`).

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain to me what exactly does `\string##` do, please? I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

Comment: @NVaughan See edit