# How to define a macro in \tcbset

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to make up a style(named `myset/.code`) of `tcolorbox` with three arguments. In this style, a macro will be re-defined. Please look at the following MWE. Yet it can not be compiled. I think someting is wrong with the defination of the style. Anyone could tell me how to modify my defination?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\stepcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mycontent}{\alph{mycounter}}

\tcbset{myset/.code n args={%
  \renewcommand{\mycontent}{%
     #1\#2{mycounter}#3%
   }}}

\begin{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem \mycontent
  \tcbitem [myset={(}{alph}{)}] \mycontent % I want get a typeout of "(a)"
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say `code n args`, the first thing after `=` has to be the number of args, which is 3 in this case. And then, in order to "prepend a backslash" you need to use `\csname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\stepcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mycontent}{\alph{mycounter}}

\tcbset{myset/.code n args={3}{%
  \renewcommand{\mycontent}{%
     #1\csname #2\endcsname{mycounter}#3%
   }}}

\begin{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem \mycontent
  \tcbitem [myset={(}{alph}{)}] \mycontent % I want get a typeout of "(a)"
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your so quick response!! Another question, if \mycontent also have its own arguments, how to distinguish them frome arguments of myset/.code?

Comment: @lyl You'd need to add another `#`, i.e `##1` for the first argument and so on.

Comment: The  another # is for arguments of myset/.code or of \mycontent?

Comment: @lyl What I meant to say is nicely explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42464/121799).