# Problem calling \creflabelformat from a command

Tags: macros, expansion, cleveref, arguments

I'm using the `cleveref` package with some customizations, using `\creflabelformat`. Because `cleveref` should be the last package to load, and because the customization commands should come after `cleveref` loads, I'd like to have a command `\loadCleveref` that loads `cleveref` and executes the customizations. That way I can define `\loadCleveref` in my standard custom package (even though `cleveref` isn't yet loaded) and then call `\loadCleveref` near the end of the document's preamble.

A problem arises when I call `\creflabelformat{snipCounter}{(S#2#1#3)}` from within `\loadCleveref`: I get `Illegal parameter number in definition of \loadCleveref` which appears to be complaining about the `#` characters. Presumably, it's confused by them, thinking that I'm referring to nonexistent arguments of \loadCleveref`.

Is there a way to execute this `\creflabelformat{snipCounter}{(S#2#1#3)}` command from within a macro?

First, what does work (i.e., when I don't try to load `cleveref` from a command):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\newcommand{\loadCleveref}{%
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefname{snipCounter}{snippet}{snippets}
    \Crefname{snipCounter}{Snippet}{Snippet}
    \creflabelformat{snipCounter}{(S#2#1#3)}
%}
%\loadCleveref
\newcounter{snipCounter}
\newenvironment{codeSnip}%
    {\refstepcounter{snipCounter}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}%
    {\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}\hspace*{\stretch{1}}(S\thesnipCounter)\end{minipage}%
    \bigskip
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{codeSnip}
\label{aSnippetLabel}
\texttt{A code snippet}
\end{codeSnip}
\Cref{aSnippetLabel} is a snippet of code.
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:
[image]

The error occurs when I un-comment the `\newcommand{\loadCleveref}` and `\loadCleveref` commands like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\loadCleveref}{%
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefname{snipCounter}{snippet}{snippets}
    \Crefname{snipCounter}{Snippet}{Snippet}
    \creflabelformat{snipCounter}{(S#2#1#3)}
}
\loadCleveref
\newcounter{snipCounter}
\newenvironment{codeSnip}%
    {\refstepcounter{snipCounter}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}%
    {\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}\hspace*{\stretch{1}}(S\thesnipCounter)\end{minipage}%
    \bigskip
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{codeSnip}
\label{aSnippetLabel}
\texttt{A code snippet}
\end{codeSnip}
\Cref{aSnippetLabel} is a snippet of code.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It'll work if you replace every `#` in the definition of `\loadCleveref` by `##`. A single `#<number>` is interpreted as an argument of `\loadCleveref` (but it doesn't have any) and `##<number>` is interpreted as `#<number>` would otherwise be interpreted. (I hope that makes sense.) See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42464/156366).

Comment: Perfect. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work if you replace every `#` in the definition of `\loadCleveref` by `##`.

Inside a macro definition, `#<number>` is interpreted as an argument of the command being defined (but `\loadCleveref` doesn't have any arguments), and `##<number>` is interpreted as `#<number>` would be interpreted outside the definition.

More information about this can for instance be found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42464/156366).

---

Here is your MWE with `#` replaced by `##`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\loadCleveref}{%
    \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefname{snipCounter}{snippet}{snippets}
    \Crefname{snipCounter}{Snippet}{Snippet}
    \creflabelformat{snipCounter}{(S##2##1##3)}
}
\loadCleveref
\newcounter{snipCounter}
\newenvironment{codeSnip}%
    {\refstepcounter{snipCounter}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}}%
    {\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[c]{0.2\textwidth}\hspace*{\stretch{1}}(S\thesnipCounter)\end{minipage}%
    \bigskip
    }%
\begin{document}
\begin{codeSnip}
\label{aSnippetLabel}
\texttt{A code snippet}
\end{codeSnip}
\Cref{aSnippetLabel} is a snippet of code.
\end{document}
```

[image]