# Prevent substitution of "macro arguments" in macro invocation within macro definition

Tags: macros, cleveref, substitution

I'm getting the error `Illegal parameter number in definition of \setuplateloadedpackages.` for the following code. It seems like `newcommand` can't recognise that the "macro arguments"
passed to `crefformat` are not its own, but placeholders to be substituted later by cleveref. I have also tried defining `\setuplateloadedpackages` using `\def` and `\let`, to no avail.

```latex
\newcommand*{\setuplateloadedpackages}{
    % Configure styles for references.
    \crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}
    \crefformat{subsection}{\S#2#1#3}
    \crefformat{subsubsection}{\S#2#1#3}
    \crefrangeformat{section}{\S\S#3#1#4 to~#5#2#6}
    \crefmultiformat{section}{\S\S#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
}
```

Comment: Double the `#` symbols if you are defining macros inside another macro: `\crefformat{section}{\S##2##1##3}`. You need to double the number of `#`s for eac nesting level.

Comment: @moewe Thank you! I tried escaping them, but didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: Would you be OK with closing this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/35864? It might not be clear a priori that `\crefformat{<counter>}{<code>}` basically works like `\def`/`\newcommand`, but once you know that, the linked question is a good duplicate. If you'd prefer a separate answer instead, just let me know, I could type something up later.

Comment: Probably nice to have a brief answer here, because that question presumes the answer to this one... hence they're different enough. Maybe just write a short answer that links to that question, and I'll gladly upvote and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of this problem `\crefformat{<counter>}{<code>}` works very similar to `\def<macroname>{<code>}`: The `#1`, `#2`, `#3` work just like normal macro arguments.

In order for TeX to properly pick up to which macro the arguments belong when you nest macro definitions, you need to double the `#s` for each nesting level as explained in [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/35864).

Because you have to say

```
\newcommand*{\setuplateloadedpackages}{%
  \newcommand*{\myfoo}[1]{Aha! ##1!}%
}
```

for LaTeX to have `\setuplateloadedpackages` properly define `\myfoo` as a macro taking a single argument and producing `Aha! <argument>!`, you also have to say

```
\newcommand*{\setuplateloadedpackages}{%
  % Configure styles for references.
  \crefformat{section}{\S##2##1##3}%
  \crefformat{subsection}{\S##2##1##3}%
  \crefformat{subsubsection}{\S##2##1##3}%
  \crefrangeformat{section}{\S\S##3##1##4 to~##5##2##6}%
  \crefmultiformat{section}{\S\S##2##1##3}{ and~##2##1##3}{, ##2##1##3}{ and~##2##1##3}%
}
```