# Custom edge in TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-graphs, tikzset

## Goal

I'm trying to connect the nodes of my graph using a horizontal-vertical-horizontal line.

## MWE

Consider the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[left anchor=east, right anchor=west] {
        a -- { b, c }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What argument do I need to pass to `\graph` to customize my edges, and how, to go from this:

[image: Current graph, produced with code above]

to this (not to scale):

[image]

## My ideas

I tried specifying the key [`/tikz/graphs/new --`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#sec-19.3.3), but I'm not sure how to do this. My main idea was to add the following to the previous code:

```latex
...
\graph[..., new --={\draw[#3] (#1) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) |- (#2) #4;}] {
...
```

and variants of that, trying to specify my function in various ways:

```latex
\graph[..., new --/.code={...}] { % or /.code 4 args or /.style
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\graph[..., every new --={...}] { % or /.code or /.code 4 args or /.style or nothing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\tikzset{ % This seemed to be a good lead too
    manhattan/.code 4 args={\draw[#3] (#1) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) |- (#2) #4;},
}

...
\graph[..., new --=manhattan] { % or /tikz/manhattan
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pgfkeys{/user/manhattan/.code 4 args={...}} % Same use as above
```

I also tested these ideas specifying the [`/tikz/graphs/default edge kind`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#sec-19.7.2) key instead of `/tikz/graphs/new --`.

Here are the two recurring error messages I encountered during my quest:

```
// Trying to define a key with /.code 4 args
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfkeys@temp.
<to be read again> 
                   3
l.7 ...[#3] (#1) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) |- (#2) #4;}]
                                                   {

--------------------------------------------------------

// Directly in \graph
! Argument of \tikz@parse@calculator has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 ...#3] (#1) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) |- (#2) #4;}]
                                                   {
?
```

Anyway, I'm lost, so thanks for any help here !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Nice first question, hope someone can answer soon

Comment: You need to do `new --/.code n args={4}{…}` and then `#1` ist the start node, `#2` is the target, `#3` is the edge's options and `#4` are the nodes. Though, I'd suggest just setting the right `to path` (for example in `/tikz/every new --`) or just for all `edges`.

Comment: `new --/.style={/user/manhattan=#1}` might work, too , if you want to use that custom style. But `.code 4 args` is not a correct handler. Pgfkeys only knows `.code` (one argument), `.code 2 args` (2), `.code n args={<n>}{…}` where `n` is less or equal 9 or `code args={???}{…}` where you can give any argument specification (just like `\def`.)

Comment: Oooh I see, I was close but didn't understand this subtility !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`new --` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/new:--) will be called with four arguments: `{⟨left node⟩}{⟨right node⟩}{⟨edge options⟩}{⟨edge nodes⟩}`.

This means you will have to overwrite it the same way. PGFKeys provides four code handlers:

1. `.code` for zero or one argument,
2. `.code 2 args` for two arguments,
3. `.code args` for a custom argument specification and
4. `.code n args` for a variable number of arguments (zero to nine)

and a bunch of variants (`.ecode`, `.add code`, etc).

You will need to use `code n args`:

```
new --/.code n args={4}{\draw[#3] (#1\tikzgraphleftanchor) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$)
                                               |- #4 (#2\tikzgraphrightanchor);}
```

I took the liberty to include the anchor specification (although they are not necessary with these connections because TikZ would automatically use the same anchor.

---

You could also adjust the `/tikz/every new --` style to use a custom `to path`, say

```
\tikzset{
  every new --/.style={
    to path={
      -|($(\tikztostart)!.5!\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
  }
}
```

but you wouldn't have access to the pure node name (or you need to parse it out again) when `\tikztostart`/`\tikztotarget` includes them.

The same applies to the `edges` key that sets all edges to the same style.

Interestingly, you can set the `new --` key as part of the options of the `--[<opt>]` syntax. Though, using it with `->` would not change anything.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, calc}
\tikzgraphsset{
  |-| connection/.style={
    new --/.code n args={4}{\draw[##3] (##1\tikzgraphleftanchor) -| ($(##1)!.5!(##2)$) |- ##4 (##2\tikzgraphrightanchor);}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\graph[left anchor=east, right anchor=west,
  new --/.code n args={4}{\draw[#3] (#1\tikzgraphleftanchor) -| ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$) |- #4 (#2\tikzgraphrightanchor);}
] {
    a -- { b, c } --[complete bipartite] {d, e, f}
  };

\tikz[>=Stealth]
  \graph[left anchor=east, right anchor=west] {
    a -- { b, c }
      --[|-| connection, complete bipartite] {d, e, f}
      ->[|-| connection, complete bipartite] {g, h}
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer ! I'll go the first way, it's a bit cleaner in IMO. Just out of curiosity, why do you need double `#` in `|-| connection/.style` definition ?

Comment: Well, you can just do `graph[|-| connection]` or `\tikzgraphsset{every graph/.append style={|-| connection}}`. Declaring it every time you need it, might not be the best approach. The doubling of `#` is a TeX thing and is required when [nesting defintions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/16595). Here, the `new --` definition is nested inside the definition of `|-| connection` where `#1` would be the argument that is given to the key `|-| connection` (which is not used however).

Comment: Oh I see ! And in my case, I only have one very large graph, so it's not a problem to define on the fly :)